# php array to jquery array to qTip plugin

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, foreach, qtip

I'm trying to get a PHP array to use in some jquery script using the qTip plugin. This is my array:

```
$descqtip[ ] = array('name' => ''.$name.'', 'description' => ''.$description.'');
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var description = <?php echo json_encode($descqtip)?>;

   $('#homepage_catgames h2').each(function(i){
      $(this).qtip({
         content: description
      })
   });
});
</script>
```

I know the above doesn't work, but i'm stuck on trying to get the description variable in each part of the array to their own individual tooltip.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What is "name" in the above php array? The name of the item that will get the given description?

Comment: 'name' is the name of the game and 'description' is the description of the game. All this is fetched from the mysql query in the code, which is in a while loop. This is how the array is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with how you are referencing the array on the Javascript side.  I went ahead and made an example of what you wanted to do.

What you need is this:

```
       var rows = <?php echo json_encode($descqtip); ?>;
       var index = 0;

       $('#sections h2').each(function()
       {
          $(this).qtip(
          {
             content: rows[index].description
          });
          index++;

       });
```

The details are covered in this article I put on my blog http://blake.breakwatersyndicate.com/2011/03/php-array-in-json/

I hope that helps.